# When would it make sense to use a Heckman selection model along with a multilevel regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, heckman

For instance, suppose I'm using a national data set which includes a measure of subjective life satisfaction for children (I'm just making this up).

- Model 1: I have variables that theory and prior research have found
  to be associated with life satisfaction.
- Model 2: I restrict the model to only children whose parents are
  homeowners, and add a categorical variable for home size relative to
  their local market (e.g., large, medium, small)
- Model 3: I restrict the model to only children whose parents are
  owners of a large home, and add a categorical variable for time that
  parents spend with their children (e.g., high, medium, low)

In what cases, if any, would it make sense to use the Heckman correction when evaluating a multilevel regression model like this? (Note: The example above was only intended to outline the "structure" of a research question--i.e., successively smaller sample sizes from the same initial sample.)